# Kivy: how to retrieve ids or active states of checkbox (or other widgets) created within python

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

My app follows 3 steps:

- In step 1, the users enter a number (all widgets are in a `.kv` file -cf the code below).
- In step 2, as many labels and checkboxes as the number entered in step 1 are generated. Then the user select some checkboxes and click on the button "OK 2".(Because the number of widgets of the second step can vary,they are created in the `.py` ―it may not be the best way to do it but I haven't found a better idea).
- In step 3, I get the active state of the checkboxes generated in step 2 and according to which one is active or not, I do some more steps.

My question is how can I get the state of the checkboxes? When they are "created", each has an id but these ids don't appear when I print `self.ids`. Also I get an error if I pass any argument to the `getcheckboxes_active` def. (None is not callable).

The `.py`:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    input_text = StringProperty("10")


    def show(self, number):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="vertical")
        for each in range(int(number)):
            layout2 = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="horizontal")
            l=Label(bold= True,font_size=20, text='Hello', markup = True)
            c= CheckBox(id = "CheckBox"+str(each))
            layout2.add_widget(l)
            layout2.add_widget(c)
            layout.add_widget(layout2)
        button = Button(text="OK 2")
        button.bind(on_press=self.getcheckboxes_active)  # self.getcheckboxes_active(self, "test") give an error None is not callable
        layout.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(layout)

        self.input_text = "Done"

    def getcheckboxes_active(self, *arg):
        '''how to get the active state of all checkboxed created in def show'''
        print(self.ids)  # CheckBoxes id aren't displayed
        print(*arg)
        print("State of all checkboxes")

class MyApp_auto(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
MyApp_auto().run()
```

The `.kv`: I need to have a .kv because the "step 1 real app" is way more complex than an TextInput and a Button.

```py
<MyWidget>
    orientation: "horizontal"
    TextInput:
        text: root.input_text
        id:input
    Button:
        text:'OK 1'
        on_press: root.show(input.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the `ids` dictionary is only populated with `id` values that were defined in the .kv file, **not** in python.

However, you can create you own dictionary that contains the references to the `CheckBox` widgets. Instead of providing the `id` property upon the creation of the widget, you could populate a dictionary attribute of `MyWidget` (let's call it `check_ref`) that links your `id` with each `CheckBox` instance:

```
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    input_text = StringProperty("10")

    check_ref = {}

    def show(self, number):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="vertical")
        for each in range(int(number)):
            layout2 = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation="horizontal")
            l=Label(bold= True,font_size=20, text='Hello', markup = True)
            c = CheckBox()

            # Stores a reference to the CheckBox instance 
            self.check_ref["CheckBox"+str(each)] = c

            layout2.add_widget(l)
            layout2.add_widget(c)
            layout.add_widget(layout2)
        button = Button(text="OK 2")
        button.bind(on_press=self.getcheckboxes_active)  # self.getcheckboxes_active(self, "test") give an error None is not callable
        layout.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(layout)

        self.input_text = "Done"

    def getcheckboxes_active(self, *arg):
        '''how to get the active state of all checkboxed created in def show'''
        # Iterate over the dictionary storing the CheckBox widgets
        for idx, wgt in self.check_ref.items():
             print(wgt.active)

        # You can also get a specific CheckBox
        # print(self.check_ref[--my id--].active)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just have troubles with the last commented print : `self.check_ref[CheckBox0].state`, I get the error `name 'CheckBox0' is not defined`, even though `print(self.check_ref)` doesn't print a `CheckBox0` id.

Comment: `CheckBox0` should be a string yes?

Comment: Sorry for that! One last question. Why is the attribute is `state` with the two vales  `normal` and `down` whereas for a checkbox from a `.kv`, the attribute is `active` and the values are `True` and `False`?

Comment: Oops, my bad! You're right, it should be the `active` attribute and not `state`. I'll correct it.

Comment: Well, I posted before checking and with `active` and it's giving me `True` and `False`. so I posted my comment a bit to quickly, sorry!

Comment: I still have another question, why can't I pass any argument to the def in the line `button.bind(on_press=self.getcheckboxes_active)`? Why can't I write `button.bind(on_press=self.getcheckboxes_active (self, "test")`?

Comment: You can, but you'll have to use either `partial` or an anonymous function. In your example you could do something like: `button.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.getcheckboxes_active("teste"))`. This may also help: https://blog.kivy.org/2014/03/kivy%E2%80%99s-bind%C2%A0method/

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a common scenario: From a list of strings, make labels and their corresponding checkbox, using the previously mentioned idea of a dictionary, then show the selected checkbox label as the text of another label.

```
class BuildRequester(BoxLayout):
    chkref = {}
    def on_checkbox_active(self,chkbox,value):
        self.ids.label2.text = 'Selected ' + self.chkref[chkbox]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BuildRequester,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        prods = [' B_0003',' B_0007',' B_0008', ' B_0200']

        for i in range(4):
            self.add_widget(Label(text=prods[i],italic=True,bold=True))
            chkbox = CheckBox(group='1',color=[0.1,1,0,4])
            chkbox.bind(active=self.on_checkbox_active)
            self.add_widget( chkbox)
            self.chkref[chkbox]= prods[i]
```